# Image in GridView Column Header ASP

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, header

I am using Grid View in ASP (Visual Studio 2010) and just wondered is there a way to but HTML code in the header of the columns. I want to put an image in the column header rather than text I have tried img html but it just writes that out. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are talking about asp.net instead of classic asp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that in header text of template field.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<img src='.../...' alt='my image' />">
....
</TemplateField>
```